# Jenkins-Run Docker: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder...: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, jenkins

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254632/copying-files-in-a-directory-to-a-docker-container-not-at-same-level-as-dockerfi) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267585/copy-failed-stat-var-lib-docker-tmp-docker-builder-referencing-the-local-folde) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950678/copy-failed-stat-var-lib-docker-tmp-docker-builder076499369-files-nginx-conf) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634361/copy-failed-stat-var-lib-docker-tmp-docker-builder700869788-private-no-such-f) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073289/dockerfile-copy-failed-stat-var-lib-docker-tmp-docker-xxxx) issue, and I've looked at every resource I can find in a google search about this error message, but none of them have worked for me.

I'm using a Jenkins job to automate the build/push of a container. To do so, I'm using the "Execute Shell" build step, and doing all of my Docker configuration within (I've tried using a pipeline, but those just don't work in my team's Jenkins configuration; consider them outside the scope of this question). The job first clones a git repository (`myrepo`), and then I have a shell script write a number of files that I want to include in the Docker container (e.g. `run.sh`), as well as a Dockerfile.

The folder structure of my Jenkins workspace is as follows, by the time the build fails:

```
|-- myrepo/
|   |-- myexe            # executable file
|   |-- testfiles/
|   |   |-- file1.txt
|   |   |-- file2.txt
|   |   |-- ...
|-- run.sh
|-- Dockerfile
```

I do not have a `.dockerignore` file.

The Dockerfile, by the time the build fails, looks like this:

```
FROM centos
USER root
# create directories
RUN mkdir -p /opt/dir1/myexe
# copy shell script
COPY run.sh /usr/bin/runprog
# copy executable
COPY myrepo/myexe /opt/dir1/myexe/       # fails on this line
COPY myrepo/testfiles /opt/dir1/myexe/
# final setup 
WORKDIR /opt/dir1/myexe/
CMD ["/opt/dir1/myexe/myexe"]
```

Now, on Jenkins, I'm executing this all in the "Execute Shell" build step, after having imported the repo earlier. I create `run.sh` and `Dockerfile` during this step, using `echo` and output redirection. The shell script being executed in Jenkins's "Execute Shell" build step looks something like this:

```
echo '#!/bin/sh
...
' > run.sh

echo 'FROM centos
...
' > Dockerfile

docker system prune -af
docker images           # I can confirm from logs that no images remain
docker build -t containername:${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG} .
```

But when I run this, the build fails on that `docker build` command:

```
Step 5/8 : COPY myrepo/myexe /opt/dir1/myexe
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder190297994/opt/dir1/myexe: no such file or directory
```

None of the other questions I've seen have solutions that have helped. My files exist locally, which I can see in the Jenkins workspace after the build fails. My files exist locally *in the `.` directory*, which I can confirm by putting `pwd` and `ls` just before the `docker build` command. I don't have a `.dockerignore` file, so Docker shouldn't be ignoring anything. But I must be missing something, as it's still not working no matter what I think to try.

What am I overlooking?

(Docker version is `Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d`)

Comment: Have you tried placing the files/dirs you copy in the same directory as your `Dockerfile`? In other words, try `cd <path/to/Dockerfile>; cp myrepo/myexe ./` I know that Dockerfiles cannot use `COPY` for files/dirs outside of your `Dockerfile`'s directory, I am not sure if that also applies for subdirectories in your Dockerfile dir, hence my suggestion.

Comment: I have tried that, in fact (did `cp myrepo/myexe myexe` and then did `COPY myexe ...` in the dockerfile). It didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried running the Dockerfile in a standalone environment? Without auotmatically creating it (but typing it yourself), without Jenkins. Hey! I got the same error running the exact copy of your `Dockerfile`. Interesting.

Comment: Dude! I removed your comment `# fails on this line` and everything worked. Remove it and try again!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your comment `# fails on this line` is the problem.
As per the Docker documentation:

> Docker treats lines that begin with # as a comment, unless the line is
>   a valid parser directive. A # marker anywhere else in a line is
>   treated as an argument.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format

Comment: This fixed the problem. I'm glad I included that bit in my example, I guess - I had line comments there in my non-minimal example too.

Comment: Yes, the information in your post made it easy to reproduce.